# Remove xml node where attribute value equals 0 with xls

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to 'strip' nodes from an xml where one of the attribute values = 0 (the Quantity).
My input xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<StockAdjustments xmlns="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments">
    <StockAdjustment Article="VL04604" Client="BHP" Status="PAXD" Unit="M2" Quantity="-96" ReasonCode="TELVERSCHI" Batch="VK00427062" HostLocation="BHP" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="VL04604" Client="BHP" Status="" Unit="M2" Quantity="0" ReasonCode="TELVERSCHI" Batch="VK00427062" HostLocation="BHP" />
</StockAdjustments>
```

The requested / expected result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<StockAdjustments xmlns="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments">
    <StockAdjustment Article="VL04604" Client="BHP" Status="PAXD" Unit="M2" Quantity="-96" ReasonCode="TELVERSCHI" Batch="VK00427062" HostLocation="BHP" />
</StockAdjustments>
```

After hours of struggling with namespaces as a noob I 'produced' the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:iws="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments"
    xmlns="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments"
    excluxxde-result-prefixes="iws">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:template match="/iws:StockAdjustments/iws:StockAdjustment[@Quantity != '0']">
           <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StockAdjustment xmlns="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments">VL04604BHPPAXDM2-96TELVERSCHIVK00427062BHP</StockAdjustment>
```

I have the feeling I'm almost there, what do I need to get the required output?

Mike

[UPDATE WITH SOLUTION]
This is the correct xslt for my 'problem' thanks to Michael

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:iws="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/iws:StockAdjustments">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="iws:StockAdjustment[@Quantity != 0]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StockAdjustment[@Quantity=0]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here's another:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/StockAdjustments">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="StockAdjustment[@Quantity != 0]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! Eclipse tells me however JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - line 3: Illegal attribute 'xpath-default-namespace' / xpath-default-namespace" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:stylesheet element!

Comment: @MikeDole Well, why is your question tagged `xslt-2.0`, when you're obviously using an XSLT 1.0 processor? Anyway, both answers will work in XSLT 1.0 too - you just need to replace `xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments"` with `xmlns:iws="http://example.com/IWS/StockAdjustments"` and add the `iws:` prefix to all element names referenced in the stylesheet.